# Centering a .container block that includes 3 images

Tags: html, css, containers

I have 3 images in a div that I need centered on my webpage. I need the 3 images centered with the main top image.

I believe the .container needs to be centered but I can not figure it out for the life of me! Thank you!

Here is the code I have made. All is working I just need the 3 images centered.

```html
<h2 class="section-title desktop-12" style="text-align: center;"></h2>
<p><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/PHOTOGRFR_JoinTheTribe_1920x500_8f70f303-f8ac-4d6a-9c52-ae8cd939349d.jpg?v=1490462024" alt="Join The Tribe" /></p>
<p> </p>
<style><!--
.container { display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 30%; margin: auto; } .image { display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; } .overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; opacity: 0; transition: .5s ease; background-color: #f03d41; } .container:hover .overlay { opacity: 1; } .text { color: white; font-size: 20px; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
--></style>
<div class="container"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Creative.jpg?5705585986642973725" alt="Creative" class="image" />
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Creative_Hover.jpg?5705585986642973725" alt="CreativeHover" class="image" /></div>
</div>
<div class="container"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Brand_Rep.jpg?5705585986642973725" alt="Brand_Rep" class="image" />
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Brand_Rep_Hover.jpg?5705585986642973725" alt="Brand_RepHover" class="image" /></div>
</div>
<div class="container"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Influencer.jpg?5705585986642973725" alt="Influencer" class="image" />
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Influencer_Hover.jpg?5705585986642973725" alt="InfluencerHover" class="image" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: any html to share also to figure out what you have done so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a wrapper div around your .container divs and then make that the same width as the image at the top and have it text-align center.

The style for this:

```
.container-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width: 1920px;
}
```

1920px comes from the image the top that you're trying to center under.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vn81brar/) of this working

The html demonstrating the wrapper is:

```
 <div class="container-wrapper">
<div class="container"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Creative.jpg?5705585986642973725" alt="Creative" class="image" />
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Creative_Hover.jpg?5705585986642973725" alt="CreativeHover" class="image" /></div>
</div>
<div class="container"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Brand_Rep.jpg?5705585986642973725" alt="Brand_Rep" class="image" />
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Brand_Rep_Hover.jpg?5705585986642973725" alt="Brand_RepHover" class="image" /></div>
</div>
<div class="container"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Influencer.jpg?5705585986642973725" alt="Influencer" class="image" />
<div class="overlay"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Influencer_Hover.jpg?5705585986642973725" alt="InfluencerHover" class="image" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. One last thing if you may know. 

When minimizing the browser down to the size of an iphone/android lets say, the images are still side by side. How would I have them stack vertically once the browser size gets narrow to easier read them?

Comment: You would do a media query to get the screen size and change the width of the .container-wrapper based on the screen size.  You can find a list of media queries here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

To make center child element(s) set this style to their parent element:

```
.parent{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
 }
```

No need to `display: block` or `margin: auto` or `position: absolute/relative` ... for child element(s).

In your case wrap the `.container` divs in a parent div that said.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you want with what you already have is to set `text-align: center` on a parent container of your `.container` divs. I've tided the code a little bit, but I've simple added a `.container-wrapper` that contains your centered elements and it should work as desired.

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}
.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: #f03d41;
}
.container:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
.text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.container-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="section-title desktop-12" style="text-align: center;"></h2>

  <p><img src=
  "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/PHOTOGRFR_JoinTheTribe_1920x500_8f70f303-f8ac-4d6a-9c52-ae8cd939349d.jpg?v=1490462024"
  alt="Join The Tribe" /></p>

  <p></p>

  <div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <img src=
      "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Creative.jpg?5705585986642973725"
      alt="Creative" class="image" />

      <div class="overlay"><img src=
      "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Creative_Hover.jpg?5705585986642973725"
      alt="CreativeHover" class="image" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <img src=
      "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Brand_Rep.jpg?5705585986642973725"
      alt="Brand_Rep" class="image" />

      <div class="overlay"><img src=
      "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Brand_Rep_Hover.jpg?5705585986642973725"
      alt="Brand_RepHover" class="image" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <img src=
      "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Influencer.jpg?5705585986642973725"
      alt="Influencer" class="image" />

      <div class="overlay"><img src=
      "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1317/8733/files/Influencer_Hover.jpg?5705585986642973725"
      alt="InfluencerHover" class="image" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I added the .container-wrapper to my container and it did not change anything. Should the .container be what is centered or something else

Comment: You should also make sure to add the rule `.container-wrapper { text-align: center }`. Did you do that?

Comment: I forgot to add the <div class="container-wrapper"> to the main div. IT WORKED!

Thank you so much for your patience I am new to this and learning a lot.